# 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace that is not included in this assmebly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I've been trying to get a custom command working now for quite some time. There are plenty of resources available online and on here, and they seem straight forward. The only problem is, my IDE keeps spitting this error and I have no idea why, considering I have (I believe) followed the guides exactly.

My C# code (in a single .cs file):

```
namespace ESPUI
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // MainWindow code here
    }

    public static class CustomCommands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Exit = new RoutedUICommand
            (
                "Exit",
                "Exit",
                typeof(CustomCommands),
                new InputGestureCollection()
                    {
                        new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)
                    }
            );
    }
}
```

The top of my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ESPUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:w="clr-namespace:ESPUI"
        Title="ESP" Height="480" Width="640" MinHeight="480" MinWidth="640">
```

My command bindings:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="w:CustomCommands.Exit" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

And my MenuItem:

```
<MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="w:CustomCommands.Exit" />
```

I get the error on line 5 of my XAML (the line with `xmlns:w="clr-namespace:ESPUI"`), and the window preview doesn't load in the designer.

I have checked things, double checked things, and triple checked things. I can't find the problem and it's driving me crazy. I've even restarted my IDE to see if it was just some bug, but still no joy.

The weird thing is I do get the "Alt+F4" in my MenuItem in the window.

Comment: Is that just designer or compile error or runtime error?

Comment: @RohitVats It compiles and runs fine, but it shows up in the errors list and my designer does not show the preview: "Problem Loading This document contains errors that must be fixed [...]". Reloading does not help.

Comment: I've added some extra code so that when the command is triggered, the application exits. It works fine, but I'm still getting the error and I still can't use the designer.